# Programming to android, My layout xml files won't update when i build the project

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, layout

I'm working currently on a test project in order to practice some of the basic features of android layout before i get to work on my project.
For now i'm experiencing with some buttons and activity change, and got stack on one frustrating problem.

At first i wasn't sure why my new Layout just won't show some buttons I've placed on it, but now the problem get weirder.
As i will soon show in my code, I've got two layout xml files, one to handle the main activity and one to handle the 2nd. at first all was well, but then I've noticed i can't see the lone button on the 2nd layout, and i couldn't understand why. i've tried to change the 2nd layout to be the main layout (just my changing the setContentView() in the main activity), but weirdly enough, the program kept calling the original layout instead of the one specified in the code (of course i've check for errors, or if it was actually have been build, it did, i also inserted errors on purpose and check that the program fail to start). 
Seeing that there might be some deeper problem, i've tried to add another button to the main layout xml file, but to no vial, the program kept starting with the old one.

I've search for answer, tried to clean my project, and rebuild it, looked for missing files in my string xml, but nothing could fix it up, I'm clueless at the moment for what went wrong.

I do assume that if i start over with the project everything will be fine, but i can't start a new project every time the problem rising. (especially if I'm doing something wrong).

here is my code:

main Activity: 
 $
package test.android.mark.III;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class AndroidMarkIII extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // bind button to the view from the xml
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openNewWindow(v);
        }
    });   
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);// bind button to the view from the xml

    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openPopupWindow(button2);
        }
    });
    }

protected void openNewWindow(View v) {
    Intent listWindowIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListWindowActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(listWindowIntent, 0);
}
}
```

My 2nd activity:
    package test.android.mark.III;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ListWindowActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);

Button returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.return_button);
returnButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();

    }
});

}

}
```

My main XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/push_button"
    android:padding="50dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/button1"
    android:text="@string/popup_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="75dp" />
<TextView   //Was added later for check reason (wasn't seen on any run)
    android:id="@+id/end"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title1" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

my 2nd XML (for the 2nd activity)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Hello World" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/return_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/return_button"
    android:visibility="visible">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

and for any case, my strings xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="hello">Hello World, AndroidMarkIIIActivity!</string>
<string name="app_name">AndroidMarkIII</string>
<string name="title1">This is a test program</string>
<string name="push_button">Push Button - 50dp</string>
<string name="popup_button">Popup Button - 75dp</string>
<string name="return_button">return Button - 10dp</string>
<string name="close_popup_button">X</string>
<string name="popup_text">this is popup - 25dp</string>
<string name="list_window_app_name">AndroidMarkIII2ndWindow</string>
</resources>
```

and my manfiest xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AndroidMarkIII" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ListWindowActivity">
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

I really hope someone will be able to solve that problem, cause it seems actually like a really silly problem, but still, can't keep working while i'm having it.

Thanks in advance
Oren

Comment: I've run into weird problems like this sometimes and later found out it's completely eclipse's fault (sometimes). If a `clean` or restart doesn't help, I sometimes make a new project and copy all the contents over from the original. ***GL***

Comment: At first glance, the code seems to be fine. Except your 2nd xml is missing the opening <LinearLayout element but that's probably a typo. If the code is correct, it must be something else, but i don't know what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises because your XML layouts are incorrect.

In `main1.xml` you are using a `RelativeLayout`, so you have to tell each view where to place itself relative to the other views, or the `ViewGroup` itself. Try adding `android:layout_below="@id/button2"` to the last `TextView` in `main1.xml`.

As @alextsc pointed out, in `main2.xml` you are telling the `TextView` to fill the entire screen with `fill_parent`. Change the height to `wrap_content` and set `android:orientation="vertical"` in the `LinearLayout` parent as [the default is `horizontal`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation).

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved everything, and made me feel a bit stupid.

Answer (score 0):

> at first all was well, but then I've noticed i can't see the lone button on the 2nd layout, and i couldn't understand why.

First of all, your XML for the second activity seems to be incomplete. You are at least missing the opening LinearLayout here. I assume this is present and there is nothing more missing *(probably just a copy&paste error)*.

What you did there is having a TextView which is set to `fill_parent` in both the width and the height. The reason you can't see your button is that there is simply no space left for it. The textview fills the parent LinearLayout completely *(if you want to visualize that, add `android:background="#ff0000"` to the textview. It's background becomes red and fills the screen)*. You can change the width and height of the textview to `wrap_content` for starters, which should make the button visible. If you intent a certain layout distribution for the two, have a look at LinearLayouts weight attribute.

When it comes to the not-changing layouts: I'm not sure what's going on here. Make sure that your XMLs are called `main1.xml` and `main2.xml`. There is also a default layout file called `main.xml`. Make sure that you didn't edit this by accident. *(sounds like you got this part covered to me, just to make absolutely sure)*